# Calling Web Service Asynchronously from ASP.NET Page is of no use

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asynchronous

Say you have to call a web service from an ASP.NET page. If you just call it asynchronously it is of no use because

The CLR Threadpool thread that would not get freed. Instead it would be blocked (or be waiting) until response is received from the web service. The only gain we get is that thread will not get CPU time (or scheduled for execution) until response is received from web service.

If we want to get true benefit of calling web service asynchronously, it has to be done from asynchronous handler (i.e. asynchronous pages).

Is it true that calling web service asynchronously from a synchronous page is useless?

Answer (score 0):

You can call it synchronously or asynchronously:

http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2010/04/02/calling-web-service-functions-asynchronously-from-a-web-page.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to do.  One scenario that would benefit is when you need to call multiple unrelated web services in the same request.